# Cauchy Schwarz inequality for trace

Tags: matrices, reference-request, trace

I found the following theorem in wikipedia.
If matrices $A$ and $B$ are positive semi-definite of the same size then $trace(AB) \leq trace(A) trace(B)$.

I need a reference book having this theorem to which I can refer. I just want to use it. I appreciate if anybody can introduce a reference for this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inequality is proven, amongst numerous others, in

> Z.P. Yang, X.X. Feng, *"A note on the trace inequality for products
>   of Hermitian matrix power."* **J. of Inequalities in Pure and App. Math.** Volume 3, Issue 5, No. 78, 2002.

In particular, it is **Lemma 2.3** in the article.

Comment: [link to the article](https://web.archive.org/web/20220621002651/http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/082_02_JIPAM/082_02.pdf)